# Moodle, mysql query users enrolment status by course

Tags: mysql, moodle

this is a query in moodle to get alumn status in courses.
A 'X' indicates user is enrolled, empty not enrolled.
We have to add a subquery for every course we have...
Could anyone help to do a better query?

```
SELECT
    user1.firstname AS Firstname,
    user1.lastname AS Lastname,
    user1.email AS Email,
    if (exists( SELECT 
        ue.id 
        FROM mdl_user_enrolments AS ue
        JOIN mdl_enrol AS en ON en.id = ue.enrolid   
        JOIN mdl_course AS course ON course.id = en.courseid
        WHERE user1.id = ue.userid AND course.id = '1'), 'X', '') as "Enrolled Course One"
    FROM mdl_user AS user1
    LEFT JOIN mdl_user_enrolments AS ue ON ue.userid = user1.id
    LEFT JOIN mdl_enrol AS en ON en.id = ue.enrolid
    LEFT JOIN mdl_course AS course ON course.id = en.courseid
    [...]
    WHERE user1.deleted='0'
```

Comment: Please, could you help me to do a better query?

Comment: You're asking for us to exercise our psychic abilities. I'm disinclined to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this but it will take a long time to process if you have a lot of users and courses

```
    SELECT CONCAT(u.id, '_', c.id) AS uniqueid,
        u.id AS userid,
        u.firstname,
        u.lastname,
        u.email,
        MAX(CASE WHEN ue.id IS NULL THEN '' ELSE 'X' END) AS enrolled,
        c.id AS courseid,
        c.fullname AS coursename
    FROM mdl_user u
    CROSS JOIN mdl_course c
    LEFT JOIN mdl_enrol e ON e.courseid = c.id
    LEFT JOIN mdl_user_enrolments ue ON u.id = ue.userid AND ue.enrolid = e.id
    WHERE u.deleted = 0
    GROUP BY u.id, c.id
```